# Association issue in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, models

I have a problem with rails associations (developing an API).

There are three tables in my_app db:

```
"tariffs":
 string   "title",
 integer  "tariff_template_id"
...

"tariff_templates":
string   "title",
integer  "service_type_id"
...

"field_templates":
string   "title",
integer  "tariff_template_id"
...
```

The problem is:
I need to get every field_template with tariff_template_id equals to tariff_template_id in "tariffs" table.

It's easy with SQL, but Rails logic is a bit different I guess.

Thanks.

Comment: Post what you would do in SQL, and we can help translate it to ActiveRecord (which isn't difficult).

Comment: Let's see. "SELECT tariffs.title, field_templates.title FROM tariffs INNER JOIN field_templates ON field_templates.tariff_template_id = tariffs.tariff_template_id;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the associations in your models are set up correctly, sounds like you simply want the following:

`Tariff.includes(:tariff_template).all`

It won't do exactly what you want (Rails works in objects), but it will return you Tariff objects and their associated TariffTemplates in minimal queries.